# Why does :first-child:before target all elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list of items which I am trying to add dividers to right of each using the :before psuedo element.

Unfortunately, it seems like when I use it in combination with both last-child and first-child, it targets every element in the list.

Example - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rupqi

**Markup**

```
<ul class="nav nav--inline nav--secondary">
        <li><a class="nav--secondary__item" href="#">Site Map</a>        </li>
            <li><a class="nav--secondary__item" href="#" title="Search Terms">Search Terms</a>        </li>
            <li><a class="nav--secondary__item" href="#" title="Advanced Search">Advanced Search</a>        </li>
                            <li><a class="nav--secondary__item" href="#" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>        </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav--inline, .nav--inline > li, .nav--inline > li > a { float: left; }

.nav--secondary__item {
    color: #706782;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0.8em;
    position: relative;
    @include transition (background-color 0.5s ease-in-out);
}

.nav--secondary__item:before {
    content: "|";
    color: #939EB7;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.nav--secondary__item:first-child:before, .nav--secondary__item:last-child:before { content: "*"; }
```

Does anyone know why this happens, and if so, how to fix it?

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: Please do not link to external code on Stackoverflow. Once that code moves, your question is useless.

Comment: @Diodeus To clarify, outside examples like jsfiddle and codepen are encouraged, but as working supplements to code posted in SO itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you have `a` elements inside `li` elements and you are applying `first-child` to those `a` elements.

So `.nav--secondary__item:first-child` applies to every `.nav--secondary__item`, because the parents for each `a` are the surrounding `li`, not your `ul`.

Going by your class naming scheme, you can change your HTML to look like this:

```
<li class="nav--secondary__item">
  <a class="nav--secondary__item__link" href="#" title="Site Map">Site Map</a>
</li>
```

And your CSS for the `first-child`/`last-child` will need a slight tweak:

```
.nav--secondary__item:first-child .nav--secondary__item__link:before,
.nav--secondary__item:last-child .nav--secondary__item__link:before { 
  content: "*"; 
}
```

You will also have to make the styles that apply to the `a` element use the `.nav--secondary__item__link` class instead.

Example forked from yours: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rknmL

Answer (score 4):

Change your css to :

```
li:first-child .nav--secondary__item:before, 
li:last-child .nav--secondary__item:before {
    content:"*";
}
```

Because `.nav--secondary__item` is first-child as well as last-child of its parent `li`, following selector applies the content to all of them.

```
.nav--secondary__item:first-child:before, 
.nav--secondary__item:last-child:before 
{ content: "*"; }
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttxUV/)**

`:first-child` pseudoclass selects the first child of its parent, similarly `:last-child`.

> The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the first child element of its parent.

See **[doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child)**